# Plot instance missing in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, nodes

I have written a small macro to draw triangles with slope in `PGFplots` axis environments. I try to draw two of these triangles. However, the first one is missing for some reason.

How can I resolve this?

Minimum working example:

```
% Mind section '4.17 Custom annotations' of the PGFplots manual Revision 1.12 (2015/01/31).
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\xmin}{-0.1}
\newcommand{\xmax}{1.1}
\newcommand{\ymin}{-0.2}
\newcommand{\ymax}{2.2}

\newcommand{\slopeTriangle}[5]
{
    % Calculate auxilliary quantities.
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xA}{\xmin+(#1+#2)*(\xmax-\xmin)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yA}{\ymin+#3*(\ymax-\ymin)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xB}{\xmin+#1*(\xmax-\xmin)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yB}{\yA}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xC}{\xA}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yC}{\yA+(\xA-\xB)*#4}

    % Define coordinates for \draw.
    \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:\xA,\yA);
    \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:\xB,\yB);
    \coordinate (C) at (axis cs:\xC,\yC);

    % Draw slope triangle.
    \draw[#5] (A)--(B) node[pos=0.5,anchor=north] {1};
    \draw[#5] (B)--(C);
    \draw[#5] (C)--(A) node[pos=0.5,anchor=west] {1};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xtick={-0.1,0,1,1.1},
            xmin=\xmin,
            xmax=\xmax,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ytick={-0.2,0,2,2.2},
            ymin=-0.2,
            ymax=2.2,
            ylabel style={rotate=-90},
            ylabel=$y$,
            unit vector ratio=2 1 1,
            clip=false
        ]
            \addplot[blue,domain=0:1] {x};
            \addplot[red,domain=0:1] {2*x};

            \slopeTriangle{0.8}{0.1}{0.1}{1}{blue}; % WHY IS THIS TRIANGLE NOT DRAWN?   
            \slopeTriangle{0.65}{0.1}{0.1}{2}{red};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside an `axis` environment, all the "normal" TikZ commands are collected when they are first encountered and only executed at a later stage when the axis is finished. At that point, the auxiliary macros contain the values for the second triangle, so the second triangle gets drawn twice and the first triangle doesn't get drawn at all. You can fix this by wrapping the triangle code in `\pgfplotsextra{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\xmin}{-0.1}
\newcommand{\xmax}{1.1}
\newcommand{\ymin}{-0.2}
\newcommand{\ymax}{2.2}

\newcommand{\slopeTriangle}[5]
{
    \pgfplotsextra{
    % Calculate auxilliary quantities.
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xA}{\xmin+(#1+#2)*(\xmax-\xmin)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yA}{\ymin+#3*(\ymax-\ymin)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xB}{\xmin+#1*(\xmax-\xmin)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yB}{\yA}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xC}{\xA}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yC}{\yA+(\xA-\xB)*#4}

    % Define coordinates for \draw.
    \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:\xA,\yA);
    \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:\xB,\yB);
    \coordinate (C) at (axis cs:\xC,\yC);

    % Draw slope triangle.
    \draw[#5] (A)--(B) node[pos=0.5,anchor=north] {1};
    \draw[#5] (B)--(C);
    \draw[#5] (C)--(A) node[pos=0.5,anchor=west] {1};
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xtick={-0.1,0,1,1.1},
            xmin=\xmin,
            xmax=\xmax,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ytick={-0.2,0,2,2.2},
            ymin=-0.2,
            ymax=2.2,
            ylabel style={rotate=-90},
            ylabel=$y$,
            unit vector ratio=2 1 1,
            clip=false
        ]
            \addplot[blue,domain=0:1] {x};
            \addplot[red,domain=0:1] {2*x};

            \slopeTriangle{0.8}{0.1}{0.1}{1}{blue}; % WHY IS THIS TRIANGLE NOT DRAWN?   
            \slopeTriangle{0.65}{0.1}{0.1}{2}{red};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I somewhat suspected what you described, and therefore tried to play around with the commands `\noexpand` and `\expandafter`, which I already encountered in the past. Couldn't get it to work though. I guess `\pgfplotsextra` has a similar sort of effect in an axis environment. Thanks for the clear explanation and solution. It really cuts down the effort I have to make to plot multiple triangles in one graph, which have to do often for my paper.